# How to move and duplicate multiple images in Excel worksheets using Python?

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlwings

I have Excel worksheets that I would like to **move / duplicate multiple images in using Python** (choosing Python due to reasons of existing infrastructure and technology choices).

Using `xlwings`, I can insert an image from either a `.png` or `.jpg` file, but cannot insert an image that comes from another worksheet in the workbook.

I am aware of the ability to insert a fig, but this appears to work only for matplotlib generated figures.  Looking through the documentation or searching online have not found relevant answers.

Using `Openpyxl`, I can insert images into a worksheet from a file (`.png` or `.jpg` file), but multiple copies of the same image causes the file to be corrupted upon save due to Zip issues -  and the images still need to come from a file not elsewhere in the workbook.

Any help on either of these modules or an explanation of how to do it another way in Python would be great.